# how to host react-js app with Hapi?

Tags: reactjs, hapi.js

I have made a react-js app with react-router. I have set up my web-app with these endpoints:

```
/home
/user/:id
```

Everything works just fine until I try to host it on ec2 instance with Hapi.

First I found this tutorial, https://medium.com/@tribou/serving-react-and-flux-with-hapi-and-webpack-213afacf94ea but seems it just generate static html pages per-request, and all the component states are lost.

Then I found this one, https://medium.com/@notrab/using-create-react-app-with-hapi-js-8f4ef3dcd311, it packs everything into build/ with only one entry file, index.html. Then do I need to manually redirect /user/:id to build/index.html?

Answer (score -1):

First you need [inert](https://github.com/hapijs/inert) plugin, register with your application.

This is my controller code for / endpoint:

```
exports.dashboard = {
    auth: false,
    description: 'main request handler',
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        return h.file('/PATH_TO_MY_BUILD_FOLDER/index.html', {confine: false});
    }
};
```

Just that, it severs index.html from my disk.

You need to handle /static/css/ and  /static/js/ folders because index.html contains links to that folders, I handled with nginx, you can use inert plugin of course, but nginx if you ask me, here is nginx config file for that

```
server {
    listen 80;    
    server_name domain.com;
    root   /home/ubuntu/myapp/build;

  # handle static files in build folder
  location ~ ^/static/(.*)$ {
      alias /home/ubuntu/myapp/build/static/$1;
  }

  location / {        
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 600;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
        proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

That's all.

Put that **/** handler to end of your route configuration, handle the **/user/:id** route long before the main **/** route.

Again, here is the route config for you:

```
server.route([
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/user/:id',
        options: Controller.userDetail
    },
    {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/user',
        options: Controller.createUser
    },        
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        config: Controller.dashboard
    },
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/{param*}',
        config: Controller.dashboard
    },
]);
```

Comment: which file do you give out in  Controller.userDetail? still index.html?

Comment: nope, you can render a view there, or you can return index.html if you like.

        return h.file('/PATH_TO_MY_BUILD_FOLDER/index.html', {confine: false});